# SQLite Implementation Android

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlite

While Implementing SQLite data base in android 
In my Application I have different 5 database tables. 
I found two ways to implement this

1)
create different database for each table and respective SQLiteOpenHelper implementation.

2)
Create 1 database and only 1 SQLiteOpenHelper implementation in that, create all the required tables

I have below queries regarding the above methods.

a) The `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();` will get database in RAM to operate on It 
In case 1) we have a separate database for each table so it will load respective database in memory ?
In case 2) We have single database having all the tables so the all the tables will come in RAM ?

b)In case 2 What if one feature updating in one table and other in 2nd table and 1st feature completed its task and calls `close` on database then what will happen to the 2nd feature which is still in process ? will there be any exception ?

Comment: Managing several databases will require handling all of them (opening, closing, ...). The amount of database data in RAM will be the same. But you would have more database objects

Comment: @1) hahahaha what for? how will you use join statment? ... @a) who cares @b) use ContentProvider, there will be only one instance of db class inside CP there will be no sens to call close on db instance at all

Answer (score 4):

This is mainly a design question.

If your tables make a consistent whole altogether, they should be stored in a same database. If they are independant, completely unrelated, with no common purpose or use case, these are as many databases.

For example: the tables `Users`, `Accounts`, `AccessRights` should be in a same database as the *Users* do have *Accounts* that are granted *AccessRights*.

Keeping data consistent across multiple tables (the *model*) is actually the purpose of a database.